# How to rename the file before uploading in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to upload same file in multiple tests and under every test the file name should be unique. So the file name should be renamed automaticaly before uplaoding. I have provided the code snippet that i have used for uplaoding below.

//Constants.java

```
 public static final String EXCEL_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources   /TestData/a.xlxs"
```

//page class //HomePage.java

```
 public void uploadCSVFileSendKeys(String filePath){
        uploadFile.sendKeys(filePath);
    }
```

//test class

```
@Test(priority =1  )
public void VerifySuccessfulFileUpload(){
    LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
    HomePage homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    loginPage.login(Constants.userName, Constants.password);
    homePage.uploadCSVFileSendKeys(Constants.EXCEL_FILE);
    homePage.uploadFile();
}
```

I tried adding "filepath + System.currentTimeMillis()", But provided an error as "File not found". Tried adding date and time to the file path, same error was thrown.

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Quick and easy solution for small files: Make a temporary copy first with the new name then your existing method works, and simply delete the temporary copy once the file is sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the original file and upload it. Once the required code is being executed, if you wish to delete then delete the file.

```
public String uploadCSVFileSendKeys(String filePath) {
        File originalFile = new File(filePath);
        File renamedFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources"
                + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(24) + ".xlxs");
        FileUtils.copyFile(originalFile, renamedFile);
        uploadFile.sendKeys(renamedFile);
        return renamedFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

To delete `File`

```
    FileUtils.delete(new File("duplicateFileLocation"));
```